# Hibernate (4.x) does not accept queries that are too long

Tags: mysql, hibernate

The query-string I have is too long when generated (doing the stress-test). By too-long, I mean, as long as 50 lines of wrapped text.

MySql accepts the query and does all it is supposed to do.  Hibernate, however, returns a null.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior in Hibernate without updating or abandoning Hibernate ?

Edit: the code I used...

```
     EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
    String qry = "FROM table WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3....repeat 5000 times"
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qry, table.class);
    List<table> tbls = query.getResultList();
    return tbls;
```

Note, all IDs exist, and IDs must be specified (can't use any range). It works when there are 1000 IDs, it does not work (returns a null) with 5000 IDs.

Comment: Could you please include the exception you got?

Comment: No exception, I simply get a null.

Comment: How do you know that there is an issue with the query length then? I think there might be some other issue. Could you please include the code you are using?

Comment: Because, when I shorten the query, it works.

Comment: Most probably it doesn't have to do anything with the query length but the query semantics. The longer query means 0 rows in the db, however the shorter one means x rows.

Comment: See the edit (posted the code I used), thank you for replying and trying to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried doing this lengthy query using pure jdbc ? Just having a `null` return is a strange behavior : hibernate always throws exception when something unexpected happens. I followed the hibernate execution stack down to `Loader.processResultSet`. There does not seem to be an path that can return null : `results` is always initialized. The only other possibility is an exception.

Comment: @Thierry Except for running the query in the command-line, I haven't tried using directly a JDBC. I might have omitted displaying the exception/log.  I will investigate. Thank you !

Comment: Don't you have any exception handling in the upper layers where you call this method?

Comment: Yes I do, but I do not get any exception... I made a work-around (changed the logic in a code), because I had to come up with something quick, and now I have no time to investigate the depths. Sorry, I was hoping this was something simpler.